# How to print number in only sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Please let me know that how to print numbers in only sql statement where our output like below:-

Number
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
.
.
100

Comment: [Oracle Row Generator Techniques](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is print this line, you have the following query:

```
select 'Number ' || listagg(cnt, ' ') within group (order by cnt)
from
(
  select level cnt
  from dual
  connect by level <= 100
);
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this will Help

```
SELECT ROWNUM n
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE ROWNUM <= 100
```